# SQL for related videos

Tags: php, sql

What I need is a query for related videos in a page that shows a video from youtube. However, it should choose related videos from my database. My table structure is:

id, privatepublic, singer, title, datetime, gender, difficulty, ytid, lang

title : (title of the song),
ytid : Yotube ID of the video,
lang : Language of the song,
difficulty : ranged from 0 to 10.

Requirements:

1. privatepublic should be 1
2. gender should be same with the current video
3. At the top same singer videos should be displayed sorted by datetime
4. After the "singer" section at 3, it should display songs with the same gender and the closest difficulty .
5. Max number of videos related should be 5.

I am a beginner for SQL. Thank you for your answers.

For now I used this integrated with PHP:

```
$qry_select="SELECT songs.* FROM songs
WHERE (((songs.gender)='".$_SESSION['gender']."')) AND 
(((songs.ytid)<>'".$_SESSION['ytid']."')) AND 
(((songs.privatepubblic)=1)) AND           (((songs.lang)='".$_SESSION['songlang']."'))
ORDER BY RAND()  
limit 0,5;";
```

Comment: Hello, have you tried anything so far? Show some effort please.

Answer (score 0):

After 2-3 days of trial I finded the code: (songInfo comes with GET)

```
(SELECT songs.* FROM songs WHERE author = '".$songInfo['author']."' 
AND lang='".$songInfo['lang']."' 
AND Title<>'".$songInfo['Title']."' 
ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 2) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM `songs` WHERE gender='".$songInfo['gender']."' 
AND lang='".$songInfo['lang']."' 
AND Title<>'".$songInfo['Title']."' 
ORDER BY ABS(difficulty-4) LIMIT 5)limit 5
```